# googlemaps API v3 cluster inside clustering doesn't work

Tags: markerclusterer

I'm using the clustering in googlemaps API.
And it works fine.
Now I have some markers at the same position (more activities in 1 building).
So I did offset the markers.
But if I click at the clustering, then often it finds a new cluster.
And that cluster doesn't open.
Here is some inmportant code:

```
var mc;
var markerCluster = {gridSize: 27, maxZoom: 15};
.
.
.
.

//OFFSET BEPALEN

var min = .999999;
var max = 1.000001;

var matA = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
var matB = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

var offsetLat = post_lat[i] * matA;
var offsetLng = post_lon[i] * matB;


//POSITIE BEPALEN MARKERS

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(offsetLat, offsetLng);

var icon = customIcons[5] || {};
marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            icon: icon.icon,
            position: point,
            map: map,
            zIndex: 9999999
});


          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }

      })(marker, i));
cluster.push(marker);
    }  
}

var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, cluster,
{imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "ACTIVITEITEN : "+activ;
}

This is the Demo: (click at '2 weken').
https://www.pctraverse.nl/Project/geoB.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there has to be a min. distance between the markers.
With ofsset random it is not always.
So I replaced the randomize with a code that has a min. of 0.000013 distance in lat and lng between markers.